# Switching to twoside results in different margins for main text and frontmatter for Dissertate template (based on book)

Tags: margins, templates, books, double-sided

I want to use the generic version (https://s3.amazonaws.com/dissertate.io/Dissertate-Generic-LaTeX.zip) of the Dissertate template (https://github.com/suchow/Dissertate) to write a thesis.
After I switched from oneside to twoside - the frontmatter is formatted with a smaller inner margin, the main text has a smaller outer margin.
Since I did not define any offset for binding, I expect the outer margin to be larger by default, thus something is messed up with the main text. Also the numbering is weird, as suddenly even numbers are on the left. But this might be expected behaviour for an odd page frontmatter.

[image: Margins change between frontmatter and main text]

This is probably some setting in the template, but I cannot fix it by my self. Does anyone have any ideas?

Minimum example after downloading the template (https://s3.amazonaws.com/dissertate.io/Dissertate-Generic-LaTeX.zip) and installing the included fonts:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[twoside]{Dissertate}
\begin{document}
\input{frontmatter/personalize}
\frontmatter
\setstretch{\dnormalspacing}
\include{chapters/introduction}
\end{document}
```

Edit1 (2021-04-29 11:35):
I do not think it is a PDF viewer issue, since the single page view from okular shows the same issue (same margins for the opposite pages vii and 1).
[image]

This is the code for the Dissertate class:

```
    % -------------------------------------------------------------------
%  @LaTeX-class-file{
%     filename        = "Dissertate.cls",
%     version         = "2.0",
%     date            = "25 March 2014",
%     codetable       = "ISO/ASCII",
%     keywords        = "LaTeX, Dissertate",
%     supported       = "Send email to suchow@post.harvard.edu.",
%     docstring       = "Class for a dissertation."
% --------------------------------------------------------------------

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{Dissertate}[2014/03/25 v2.0 Dissertate Class]
\LoadClass[12pt,oneside, letterpaper]{book}

%
% Options
%
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{float}

% Line spacing: dsingle/ddouble
%   Whether to use single- or doublespacing.
\newtoggle{DissertateSingleSpace}
\togglefalse{DissertateSingleSpace}
\DeclareOption{dsingle}{
    \toggletrue{DissertateSingleSpace}
    \ClassWarning{Dissertate}{Single-spaced mode on.}
}
\DeclareOption{ddouble}{\togglefalse{DissertateSingleSpace}}

\ProcessOptions\relax

% Line Spacing
%   Define two line spacings: one for the body, and one that is more compressed.
\iftoggle{DissertateSingleSpace}{
    \newcommand{\dnormalspacing}{1.2}
    \newcommand{\dcompressedspacing}{1.0}
}{
    \newcommand{\dnormalspacing}{2.0}
    \newcommand{\dcompressedspacing}{1.2}
}

% Block quote with compressed spacing
\let\oldquote\quote
\let\endoldquote\endquote
\renewenvironment{quote}
    {\begin{spacing}{\dcompressedspacing}\oldquote}
    {\endoldquote\end{spacing}}

% Itemize with compressed spacing
\let\olditemize\itemize
\let\endolditemize\enditemize
\renewenvironment{itemize}
    {\begin{spacing}{\dcompressedspacing}\olditemize}
    {\endolditemize\end{spacing}}

% Enumerate with compressed spacing
\let\oldenumerate\enumerate
\let\endoldenumerate\endenumerate
\renewenvironment{enumerate}
    {\begin{spacing}{\dcompressedspacing}\oldenumerate}
    {\endoldenumerate\end{spacing}}

% Text layout.
\RequirePackage[width=5.75in, letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\RaggedRight
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\parindent 12pt
\RequirePackage{lettrine}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage{verbatim}

% Fonts.
\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{url}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{mathspec}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Numbers={Proportional}]{EB Garamond}
\setmathrm{EB Garamond}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\addfontfeature{RawFeature=+tnum}}
\widowpenalty=300
\clubpenalty=300
\setromanfont[Numbers=OldStyle, Ligatures={Common, TeX}, Scale=1.0]{EB Garamond}
\newfontfamily{\smallcaps}[RawFeature={+c2sc,+scmp}]{EB Garamond}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase, BoldFont={Lato Bold}]{Lato Regular}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Source Code Pro}
\RequirePackage[labelfont={bf,sf,footnotesize,singlespacing},
                textfont={sf,footnotesize,singlespacing},
                justification={justified,RaggedRight},
                singlelinecheck=false,
                margin=0pt,
                figurewithin=chapter,
                tablewithin=chapter]{caption}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\RequirePackage{microtype}


% Headings and headers.
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage[tiny, md, sc]{titlesec}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\pagestyle{plain}
\RequirePackage{titling}

% Front matter.
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalsize \scshape}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{Listing of figures}
\renewcommand\listtablename{Listing of tables}

% Endmatter
\renewcommand{\setthesection}{\arabic{chapter}.A\arabic{section}}

% References.
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\RequirePackage[super,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{[#1]}
\RequirePackage[palatino]{quotchap}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-0.5\baselineskip}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace{1.3\baselineskip}}

% An environment for paragraph-style section.
\providecommand\newthought[1]{%
   \addvspace{1.0\baselineskip plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}%
   \noindent\textsc{#1}%
}

% Align reference numbers so that they do not cause an indent.
\newlength\mybibindent
\setlength\mybibindent{0pt}
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
    {\chapter*{\bibname}%
     \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
     \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}
          {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{999}}
           \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\dimexpr\labelsep+\mybibindent\relax\itemindent-\mybibindent
           \@openbib@code
           \usecounter{enumiv}
           \let\p@enumiv\@empty
           \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}
     \sloppy
     \clubpenalty4000
     \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
     \widowpenalty4000%
     \sfcode`\.\@m}
    {\def\@noitemerr
      {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}
     \endlist}

% Some definitions.
\def\advisor#1{\gdef\@advisor{#1}}
\def\coadvisorOne#1{\gdef\@coadvisorOne{#1}}
\def\coadvisorTwo#1{\gdef\@coadvisorTwo{#1}}
\def\committeeInternal#1{\gdef\@committeeInternal{#1}}
\def\committeeInternalOne#1{\gdef\@committeeInternalOne{#1}}
\def\committeeInternalTwo#1{\gdef\@committeeInternalTwo{#1}}
\def\committeeExternal#1{\gdef\@committeeExternal{#1}}
\def\degreeyear#1{\gdef\@degreeyear{#1}}
\def\degreemonth#1{\gdef\@degreemonth{#1}}
\def\degreeterm#1{\gdef\@degreeterm{#1}}
\def\degree#1{\gdef\@degree{#1}}
\def\department#1{\gdef\@department{#1}}
\def\field#1{\gdef\@field{#1}}
\def\university#1{\gdef\@university{#1}}
\def\universitycity#1{\gdef\@universitycity{#1}}
\def\universitystate#1{\gdef\@universitystate{#1}}
\def\programname#1{\gdef\@programname{#1}}
\def\pdOneName#1{\gdef\@pdOneName{#1}}
\def\pdOneSchool#1{\gdef\@pdOneSchool{#1}}
\def\pdOneYear#1{\gdef\@pdOneYear{#1}}
\def\pdTwoName#1{\gdef\@pdTwoName{#1}}
\def\pdTwoSchool#1{\gdef\@pdTwoSchool{#1}}
\def\pdTwoYear#1{\gdef\@pdTwoYear{#1}}
% School name and location
\university{Monsters University}
\universitycity{Monstropolis}
\universitystate{Earth}

% School color found from university's graphic identity site:
% http://isites.harvard.edu/icb/icb.do?keyword=k75408&pageid=icb.page392732
\definecolor{SchoolColor}{rgb}{0.5, 0.5, 0.5} % Crimson
\definecolor{chaptergrey}{rgb}{0.5, 0.5, 0.5} % for chapter numbers

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=SchoolColor,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=SchoolColor,
}



% Formatting guidelines found in:
% http://www.gsas.harvard.edu/publications/form_of_the_phd_dissertation.php
\renewcommand{\frontmatter}{
    \input{frontmatter/personalize}
    \maketitle
    \copyrightpage
    \abstractpage
    \tableofcontents
    % \listoffigures % optional
    \dedicationpage
    \acknowledgments
}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \vspace{100pt}
    \begin{center}
    \Huge \textcolor{SchoolColor}{\thetitle} \normalsize \\
    \vspace{100pt}
    \textsc{a dissertation presented \\ by\\
    \theauthor\\ to\\ The Department of \@department\\
    \vspace{12pt}
    in partial fulfillment of the requirements\\
    for the degree of\\ \@degree\\
    in the subject of\\ \@field\\
    \vspace{12pt}
    \@university\\ \@universitycity, \@universitystate\\
    \@degreemonth\ \@degreeyear}
    \end{center} \vspace*{\fill}
}

\newcommand{\copyrightpage}{
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \scshape \noindent \small \copyright \small 2014\hspace{3pt}-- \theauthor \\
    \noindent all rights reserved.
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \newpage
    \rm
}

\newcommand{\abstractpage}{
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \setcounter{page}{3}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \lhead{Thesis advisor: Professor \@advisor} \rhead{\@author}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
    \vspace*{35pt}
    \begin{center}
    \Large \textcolor{SchoolColor}{\@title} \normalsize \\
    \vspace*{20pt}
    \scshape Abstract \\ \rm
    \end{center}
    \input{frontmatter/abstract}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \newpage \lhead{} \rhead{}
    \cfoot{\thepage}
}

\newcommand{\dedicationpage}{
    \newpage \thispagestyle{fancy} \vspace*{\fill}
    \scshape \noindent \input{frontmatter/dedication}
    \vspace*{\fill} \newpage \rm
}

\newcommand{\acknowledgments}{
    \chapter*{Acknowledgments}
    \noindent
    \input{frontmatter/thanks}
    \vspace*{\fill} \newpage
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
}


\renewcommand{\backmatter}{
    \begin{appendices}
        \include{chapters/appendixA}
    \end{appendices}
    \input{endmatter/personalize}
    \clearpage
    \bibliography{references}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
    \bibliographystyle{apalike2}
    \include{endmatter/colophon}
}
```

Comment: I don't think so. It is your previewer which cannot display two-sided documents correctly. Adobe Reader is (last I checked) known to be bad as this. The first page listed in your image should be a right hand page, not a left hand page like in the image. Thus in a correct two sided display the margins are correct.

Comment: In Adobe viewer, go to View, Page Display, Show Cover Page in Two Page View.  Also, in the same menu, you could choose Two Page Scrolling.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: I am on Linux MINT using evince or okular for looking at the document. When looking at it in a single-page view it is the same (I edit my post and add this view as well). So I suspect it is not just a viewer issue. Can you confirm this on your machine?

Comment: Ahh, for Evince remove the tick mark on `Odd pages left` in the configuration (the icon with a wrench on it)

Comment: The issue is that two consecutive pages have the same margins, which does not work when printed in duplex. I am almost positive that there is no viewer issue here (the image was taken with okular).

Comment: Can you then please provide something that others can copy and test. I don't know any classes named `Dissertate`

Comment: I include the download link and the github repository for the template I am having the issue with. I believe the easiest option to test is to download it, and use my modified code to see the effect - right? I add the Dissertate.cls from that template above.

Comment: Erh, `\LoadClass[12pt,oneside, letterpaper]{book}` do you get any `unused option twoside` in your log? Note the explicit `oneside`, and from what I can see there are no options indicating that it supports other class options other than  `dsingle` and `ddouble`

Comment: You might want to replace your fincluded txt which we do not have access to by `\kant` from the `kantlipsum` package (it provides sample text)

Comment: In short the class you use does not support `twoside`. Were you asked to use this class or is it just one you found in the internet? If the latter, you might want to use something else, even the caption settings in it fails (it asks for an upsupported option as far as I can tell).

Comment: Let's assume I have to use it. What changed would I need to make to the class definition to have a consistent twosided setup?